# I have a error when i want to compile aseprite with ninja?

Tags: compilation, ninja

This is a part of the error

```
C:\asesprite\build>ninja aseprite
[1/1202] Building C object
```

third_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_entry_strmode.c.obj
FAILED: third_party/libarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/archive_static.dir/archive_entry_strmode.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo -DCMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -DNDEBUG -DPNG_NO_MMX_CODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\third_party\tinyxml -IC:\asesprite\third_party\pixman\pixman -IC:\asesprite\build -IC:\asesprite\third_party\giflib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\jpeg -IC:\asesprite\third_party\curl\include -IC:\asesprite\third_party\simpleini -IC:\asesprite\third_party. -IC:\MinGW\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /MT /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG -MT /showIncludes /Fothird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_entry_strmode.c.obj /Fdthird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_static.pdb /FS -c C:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive\archive_entry_strmode.c
C:\MinGW\include\msvcrtver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\w32api.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sdkddkver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(38): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(593): warning C4142: '__time32_t': benign redefinition of type
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(139): note: see declaration of '__time32_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(631): error C2371: 'time_t': redefinition; different basic types
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(149): note: see declaration of 'time_t'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'unsigned' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'short' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(210): error C2628: '_pid_t' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\stdint.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(204): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(210): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(235): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(354): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
st64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(558): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
IC:\asesprite\third_party. -IC:\MinGW\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /MT /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG -MT /showIncludes /Fothird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_hmac.c.obj /Fdthird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_static.pdb /FS -c C:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive\archive_hmac.c
C:\MinGW\include\msvcrtver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\w32api.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sdkddkver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(38): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(593): warning C4142: '__time32_t': benign redefinition of type
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(139): note: see declaration of '__time32_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(631): error C2371: 'time_t': redefinition; different basic types
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(149): note: see declaration of 'time_t'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'unsigned' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'short' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(210): error C2628: '_pid_t' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\stdint.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(204): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(210): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(235): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(354): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(360): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(665): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(666): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(667): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(668): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(166): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(169): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(335): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(336): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(338): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(339): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(342): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(343): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(344): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(361): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(363): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(364): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(367): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(368): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(379): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(382): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
[5/1202] Building C object third_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_acl.c.obj
FAILED: third_party/libarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/archive_static.dir/archive_acl.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo -DCMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -DNDEBUG -DPNG_NO_MMX_CODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\third_party\tinyxml -IC:\asesprite\third_party\pixman\pixman -IC:\asesprite\build -IC:\asesprite\third_party\giflib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\jpeg -IC:\asesprite\third_party\curl\include -IC:\asesprite\third_party\simpleini -IC:\asesprite\third_party. -IC:\MinGW\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /MT /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG -MT /showIncludes /Fothird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_acl.c.obj /Fdthird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_static.pdb /FS -c C:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive\archive_acl.c
C:\MinGW\include\msvcrtver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\w32api.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sdkddkver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(38): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(593): warning C4142: '__time32_t': benign redefinition of type
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(139): note: see declaration of '__time32_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(631): error C2371: 'time_t': redefinition; different basic types
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(149): note: see declaration of 'time_t'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'unsigned' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'short' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(210): error C2628: '_pid_t' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\stdint.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(204): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(210): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(235): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(354): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(360): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(381): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(484): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(490): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(491): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(492): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(493): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(336): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(338): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(339): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(342): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(343): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(344): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(361): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(363): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(364): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(367): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(368): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(379): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(382): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
[7/1202] Building C object third_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_options.c.obj
FAILED: third_party/libarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/archive_static.dir/archive_options.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo -DCMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -DNDEBUG -DPNG_NO_MMX_CODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\third_party\tinyxml -IC:\asesprite\third_party\pixman\pixman -IC:\asesprite\build -IC:\asesprite\third_party\giflib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\jpeg -
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(517): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(518): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(519): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(556): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(557): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(558): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(559): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(564): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(566): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(567): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(568): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(569): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(570): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(579): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(585): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(587): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(595): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(597): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(598): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(599): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(600): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(607): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(608): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(615): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(617): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(622): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(623): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(624): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(651): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(652): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(653): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(654): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(655): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(656): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(657): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(658): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(659): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(660): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(661): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(662): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(663): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(664): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(665): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(666): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(667): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(668): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(166): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(169): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(335): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(336): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(338): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(339): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(342): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(343): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(344): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(361): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(363): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(364): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(367): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(368): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(379): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(382): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
[8/1202] Building C object third_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_entry.c.obj
FAILED: third_party/libarchive/libarchive/CMakeFiles/archive_static.dir/archive_entry.c.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1429~1.301\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo -DCMARK_STATIC_DEFINE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -DNDEBUG -DPNG_NO_MMX_CODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libarchive -IC:\asesprite\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\zlib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\build\third_party\libpng -IC:\asesprite\third_party\tinyxml -IC:\asesprite\third_party\pixman\pixman -IC:\asesprite\build -IC:\asesprite\third_party\giflib -IC:\asesprite\third_party\jpeg -IC:\asesprite\third_party\curl\include -IC:\asesprite\third_party\simpleini -IC:\asesprite\third_party. -IC:\MinGW\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /MT /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG -MT /showIncludes /Fothird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_entry.c.obj /Fdthird_party\libarchive\libarchive\CMakeFiles\archive_static.dir\archive_static.pdb /FS -c C:\asesprite\third_party\libarchive\libarchive\archive_entry.c
C:\MinGW\include\msvcrtver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\w32api.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sdkddkver.h(35): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(38): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(593): warning C4142: '__time32_t': benign redefinition of type
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(139): note: see declaration of '__time32_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(631): error C2371: 'time_t': redefinition; different basic types
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(149): note: see declaration of 'time_t'
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'unsigned' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(209): error C2628: '_mode_t' followed by 'short' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\sys/types.h(210): error C2628: '_pid_t' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
C:\MinGW\include\stdint.h(34): warning C4068: unknown pragma 'GCC'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(201): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(204): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(207): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(210): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_findfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(232): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(235): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(351): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(354): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirsti64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(357): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(360): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_wfindfirst64'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(378): error C2059: syntax error: ''
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(381): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(484): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(490): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(491): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(492): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(493): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(494): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
C:\MinGW\include\io.h(495): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'

```
C:\MinGW\include\stdlib.h(385): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

C:\asesprite\build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using MinGW. They doesn't support mingw to compile. In my case, what I'm ended up doing is -

1. Delete all files in build folders..
2. In my case, my MinGW folder is in c:/msys64, so I renamed my folder name of msys64..
3. Compile cmake again in build folder..
4. Then run ninja aesprite
5. Done!
6. Now you can rename your mingw folder to normal and use again. (My case : c:/msys64asdf to c:/msys64)

Good luck.